# How to set initial state in useState and useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I might be not understanding completely the principals oh `useState` hook and there is a problem I came across a few times now.

I'm trying to set an initial state in my component using `useEffect` without dependencies and later on compare it to some other variables I get from `redux`.

```js
// get the customer saved in redux
const Customer = useGetCustomer();

const [prevCustomerNumber, setPrevCustomerNumber] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
// if there is already customer saved in redux, set it as the previous customer on mount
    const { CustomerNumber } = Customer || {}
    setPrevCustomerNumber(CustomerNumber)
}, [])

const submit = () => {
//check if there is any change between the customer in redux and the previous one
  const { CustomerNumber } = Customer || {}
  const submitWithoutChanges = Customer && ( CustomerNumber === prevCustomerNumber)
  submitCustomer(Customer, submitWithoutChanges )
}
```

My problem is - when clicking submit, `prevCustomerNumber` is always null.
My questions are:

1. Is it because `useState` runs again after the first `useEffect` and override it?
2. What should I do to save initial state properly?

Comment: Maybe you need to consider using `useCallback`?

Answer (score 0):

you can set your initial state of prevCustomerNumber as

```
const [prevCustomerNumber, setPrevCustomerNumber] = useState("some value")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you get the customer from redux only when the component renders. When you click submit button, the function does not tries to read the data from redux again and only uses the data that already has which may be wrong or null. In order to have the latest data from redux store you need to wrap your component with the [Connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) function:

```
export default connect ((state) => {
  const customerNumber = state.customer.customerNumber
  return {customerNumber}
})(YourComponent)
```

YourComponent will now receive the customerNumber props **every time** your redux store changes.

Or if you prefer hooks you can use [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#useselector) hook:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
const customerNumber = useSelector(state => state.customer.customerNumber)
```

Now every times the components renders or the redux store changes the useSelector hook will return the update value